# Can I use a pointer as the parameter of gets in C?

Tags: c, pointers, gets

I am studying the C language.

When I pass a pointer to gets(), I find it can work well.

```
char *ptr;
gets(ptr);
puts(ptr);
```

But if I define an array of pointers, it doesn't work.

```
char *ptr[4];
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<4;++i)
    gets(ptr[i]);
for(i=0;i<4;++i)
    puts(ptr[i]);
```

Are they different, or is the first part wrong in fact? I want to know the reason.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the pointer to point to.

Comment: Never *ever* call `gets`! It's a [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) function, which have even been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: you also need to stop using `gets`: it's deprecated and a huge security risk

Comment: There is also the `gets_s` alternative function too which also performs bounds-checking.

Comment: As for your problem, if you have a pointer you need to make it actually *point* somewhere before attempting to use it. Attempting to dereference an invalid pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a pointer to a function (e.g. `gets()`) that writes data to a memory location pointed by your pointer. In your case, you have the *uninitialized* pointer, which means it points to a random memory location (where applications or an operating system resides). This leads to random effects - from "working" to abnormal termination or hanging. You need to reserve memory and assign pointer to point there, e.g. by:

```
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(256);

gets(ptr);
puts(ptr);

free(ptr);
```

Consider to use `gets_s()` that is more secure.

Comment: Note that `gets_s()` is only available on Windows.  Using `fgets()` is a reasonable alternative, but it does retain the newline whereas `gets_s()` removes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *ptr[4];
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<4;++i)
    gets(ptr[i]);
```

This is not valid C code as you did not allocate space for `ptr[i]`.  On the other hand, never use `gets` because it's a function that does not check for buffer limit.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer has to point somewhere first.

```
#define BUFSIZE 100

char *ptr = malloc(BUFSIZE);
fgets(stdin, ptr, BUFSIZE);
puts(ptr);

char *ptr[4];
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<4;++i) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(BUFSIZE);
    fgets(ptr[i], BUFSIZE, stdin);
}
for(i=0;i<4;++i) {
    puts(ptr[i]);
}
```

Comment: regarding: `fgets(stdin, ptr, BUFSIZE);`  The syntax for `fgets()` is: `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`  so the posted code is nonsense

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry, I misremembered the argument order.